# Unable to load a gem that I built

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I referred to [this link](https://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/) to build a Ruby gem. After doing:

```
gem build hola.gemspec
```

when I try to require the gem in irb, it throws this error:

```
LoadError (cannot load such file -- word_counter_gem)
```

Can you tell me what the issue is?

Comment: No, But why do we have to commit?

Comment: Did you install the built gem? `gem install hola.gem` or equivalent

Comment: yes, I restarted the terminal and now its working. I think there was some issue with rvm.